# CsvHelper: An element with the same key '' already exists in the ExpandoObject

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

With code similar to, I receive the exception:

> An element with the same key '' already exists in the ExpandoObject

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader("SampleData.csv"))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
{
    var records = csv.GetRecords<dynamic>();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is simply due to CsvHelper is using the column headers by default as the name of the dynamic object's properties:

It is important to ensure `csvReaderConfig.HasHeaderRecord = false;` is set or to use another technique such as mapping to a class.

```
var csvReaderConfig = new Configuration();

csvReaderConfig.HasHeaderRecord = false;

using (var reader = new StreamReader("SampleData.csv"))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, csvReaderConfig))
{
    var records = csv.GetRecords<dynamic>();
}
```